# What is lattice with arbitrary suprema called?

Tags: terminology, lattice-orders

[Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Open_sets_definition) is a system of sets, which is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections.

Is there a name for [lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29), which has analogous properties, i.e., every subset has supremum. 
(And also every finite subset has infimum, but this is already in the definition of lattice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lattice with suprema for *all* subsets is called a **complete lattice**, or perhaps a **cocomplete lattice** if you are category-theoretically inclined. Here's a fun fact: any lattice that has suprema for all subsets also has *infima* for all subsets. The infimum of a subset is, of course, the supremum of all the lower bounds for that subset.

Unfortunately, a homomorphism of lattices need not preserve infinite suprema/infima, and here is where the subtlety is: for example, when one says "(co)complete join semilattice", one is thinking of homomorphisms that preserves all suprema, even though a (co)complete join semilattice is automatically a complete lattice. A continuous map of topological spaces induces a homomorphism on the lattice of open sets that preserves finite meets and infinite joins, which is precisely the definition of a homomorphism of frames. (A **frame** is a complete lattice that satisfies the infinite distributive law.)

Comment: Normally one defines a complete lattice to be one that has suprema **and** infima for all subsets.

Comment: You *fun fact* is a relatively easy observation, I should have noticed that. But I'm glad I haven't - since otherwise I would not learn from your answer about relation of this question to frames.

Comment: In Gratzer's new book, this result is the very first result shown about complete lattices in the chapter on complete lattices, [p.50](http://books.google.com/books?id=6XJX5-zCoIQC&pg=PA50).

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$If $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a topological space, $\langle\tau,\subseteq\rangle$ is a complete distributive lattice: for any $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$, $\bigvee\mathscr{U}=\bigcup\mathscr{U}$, and $\bigwedge\mathscr{U}=\int\bigcap\mathscr{U}$, and for any $U,V,W\in\tau$ we have $$U\land(V\lor W)=U\cap(V\cup W)=(U\cap V)\cup(U\cap W)=(U\land V)\lor(U\land W)$$ and $$U\lor(V\land W)=U\cup(V\cap W)=(U\cup V)\cap(U\cup W)=(U\lor V)\land(U\lor W)\;.$$ What distinguishes the two is infinite distributivity: for any $V\in\tau$

$$V\land\bigvee\mathscr{U}=V\cap\bigcup\mathscr{U}=\bigcup_{U\in\mathscr{U}}(V\cap U)=\bigvee_{U\in\mathscr{U}}(V\land U)\;,$$

but it’s not true in general that

$$V\lor\bigwedge\mathscr{U}=V\cup\int\bigcap\mathscr{U}\overset{?}=\int\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}}(V\cup U)=\bigwedge_{U\in\mathscr{U}}(V\lor U)\;.$$

What you really want to talk about, I suspect, are [frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Heyting_algebra); see also [pointless topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology) (a name that I occasionally find regrettably apt!).